# Bootstrap dropdown using accordion is not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing bootstrap dropdown in my Angular application using accordion. When I click on accordion toggle, it is not sliding down and up.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt100 mr5 ml5">
    <div class="row">
        <table class='table s12'>
            <tr style="background: #e4e9eb;">
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Edit</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="listItem in Items">
                <td>
                    {{listItem.name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{listItem.address}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{listItem.city}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  colspan="3" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="collapse"  collapse="isCollapsed">
                        <table class="table display" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class='pix2' style="background: #e4e9eb;">
                                    <th>First</th>
                                    <th>Second</th>
                                    <th>Third</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr  ng-repeat='item in listItem.subItems'>
                                    <td>{{item.first}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.second}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.third}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is causing the issue?

Comment: did you include the necessary javascript files?  Is there anything in the console?

Comment: In the controller I was mentioned  **$scope.isCollapsed = true;**. there is no error in the console.

Comment: Yes, I included all Javascipt files.

Comment: post your code for controller

Comment: @Sajeetharan, there is no code inside the controller. Just **$scope.isCollapsed = true;**